# matlab butterworth filter

Tags: matlab, filter, octave

I need to apply a butterworth filter. To prove my cutoff frequency I need to do a plot ''residuals vs cutoff frequency'' like in the 2nd sqare of the picture.

residuals come from

[image]

So I want to apply a

-butterworth filter

-lowpass

- order n=2
- cutoff frequency wn= [0,20] Hz

So my doubt is if there is a way to find the residuals by matlab. And then plot them against cutoff frequency.

Any help is huge appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take your input signal (call it `x`) and do something like

```
[b,a]=butter(2, [0 0.3]) % assuming the cutoff is 0.3 times the Nyquist frequency
y = filter(b,a,x)
n = length(x)
z = x - y
z = z.^2
z = sum(z) / n
R = sqrt(z)
```

Comment: (1) for the butter i do [b,a]=butter(2, [0 20]) ?        (2)i dont know how to get the filtered data to do what you told me(z = x - y). is there a way? can you help me please? thank you so much.

Comment: I edited my response to include that part, which involves the `filter` function. Next time, try to be more clear in your question.

Comment: it still does not work. http://i49.tinypic.com/2iszbfd.jpg  can you tell me the problem? thank you so much

Comment: Ah yes, I hadn't used MATLAB in a while. My bad. I corrected my answer again.

Comment: i am sorry. i did not understand the o,3. my sampling freq is 40 and so i am trying the frq from 0 to 0,5fs (nyquist). can you explain me this 0,3?i did not understand.

Comment: and then to plot i insert this plot([0 20],R)  ?

Comment: 0.3 is an example. 0 corresponds to f = 0, whereas 1 corresponds to f = fs/2. As for sweeping several f values and plotting the curve, that's basic MATLAB; have you read a MATLAB tutorial yet? If yes, which one?

Comment: thank you so much for your kindness. if you please can see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570306/matlab-butterworth i am very grateful than you