# Filtering a .wav file in matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, filtering

1. I have to read a wav file via MATLAB and plot it in time domain.
2. Then, transform it to frequency domain by fourier transform.
3. Next, i have to filter it in the frequencies between 0 Hz- 1 kHz, 1 kHz-5 kHz and 5 kHz-10 kHz.
4. After all, i have to plot the filtered wav file.

I handled the first 2 steps by the code;

```
    %%Reading file

    y=audioread('Recording.wav'); 
    [y, Fs] = audioread('Recording.wav'); 
    N= length(y); 
    t= [0:1/Fs:(N-1)/Fs]; 
    subplot(211) 
    plot(t,y),title('Time Domain'),xlabel('Time (s) '),ylabel('Amplitude')

    %%Fourier Transform
    f=Fs/N.*(0:N-1); 
    Y=fft(y,N); 
    Y=abs(Y(1:N))./(N/2); 
    subplot(212) 
    plot(f,Y),title('Frequency Domain'),xlabel('Frequency(Hz)'),ylabel('Amplitude')
```

So i got this graph:

[image: So i got this graph]

I tried to design a filter with Filter Builder and Filter Design & Analysis apps. However, i couldnt manage.

Comment: Do you have the signal processing toolbox ? btw, the first call to `audioread` is useless.

Comment: You can design a butterworth filter as done in the [matlab examples of `butter`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html#examples) or one of the many [SO posts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13571268/7621674)

Comment: @G.J Yes i have. I am designing the filter in filter designer, i click export when i finish but i dont know where it goes

Comment: @m7913d I still dont understand how to design a butterworth filter. Can you help me?

Comment: You can just follow the examples, with `Fs` as in your code and `fc` your filter frequencies, ex. `[1000 5000]` to filter 1kHz - 5kHz

Comment: As a side note, you may want to use fftshift before plotting your fft. Due to the real input, fft is symmetric.